# ViewStart.cshtml does not seem to be read from views

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am building a new ASP.Net Core 2.0 from the empty site template and I am trying to get the *_ViewStart.cshtml* page working. I have crated the *Views -> Shared -> _ViewStart.cshtml* page with the following code in it:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

In my *Index.cshtl* file I use for my landing page view I have this code:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

If I run an F5 debug in Visual Studio 2017 the index page loads up and just shows "Index", if I look at the source code there is no HTML from my layout. If I uncomment the Layout line and reload the page everything works fine. The two layout paths are identical in both files so why is the *Index.cshtml* file not reading from *_ViewStart.cshtml*?

I am not sure if I just missed adding a package or something to make this work or does ViewStart not work in .NET Core liked it did in .NET 4.5?

Comment: Wrong folder. it  is suppose to be in the root view folder *Views -> _ViewStart.cshtml* not the *Shared* folder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works like it did before. This is a case of putting it in the wrong folder.

It (*_ViewStart.cshtml*)  is suppose to be in the root view folder *Views/_ViewStart.cshtml* not the *Views/Shared* folder

> Neither `_ViewStart.cshtml` nor `_ViewImports.cshtml` are typically placed in the `/Views/Shared` folder. The app-level versions of these files should be placed directly in the `/Views` folder.

Reference [Layout in ASP.NET Core : Running Code Before Each View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.0#running-code-before-each-view)

Comment: Yep, you got me on that one. I was actually using that page to try and debug and was just miss aligning the folder structure in there picture. I feel stupid now